# Uipickerview is not sorted although my array is sorted

Tags: arrays, xcode, sorting, uipickerview

I have an array which is already sorted, even I sort it once more by this:

```
let sortedListOfBanks = listOfBanks.sorted()
```

I am sure it works because I check it on output.

But when I run the application picker view comes with a non-alphabetical order.

[image: code]

[image: screenshot]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can put the code in here in a code block.

Comment: Could you post the picker view datasource code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was becouse I put the savecontext out of for loop